# Docker Hub on AirGap Widows 2019 Server With No Internet Connection

Tags: docker

I am bit stuck on how to do following, excuse me if this is not actually fit StackOverFlow rules.

**We have**

- VM Workstation With Windows 2019 Server (Host)
- No Internet Connection on server as a company policy

**What I am Planning To Achieve**

- Run Multiple Docker Containers on Windows Server 2019 Host
- Docker Container 1(Private Docker Hub) : Function similar to Docker Hub where users can pull images and push new images.
- Docker Container 2 : Python Container. This container is build by pulling image from Container 1(Private Docker Hub). i.e., When user execute command `docker pull python` on Windows Server 2019 Host, instead of pulling image from Docker Hub(Remember no internet), it should pull the image from Container 1.

I have searched google there are lot of air-gap articles but not very clear on how to approach problem like this with complete air-gap.

Any pointers or directions will really help me.

Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can point Docker client to you private registry: https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-your-own-registry/

To seed your registry you need computer with acces to internet to pull image and then push to your private registry.

Consider security implications when running public images in restricted environment.

Comment: There is no computer with internet, this is complete air gap.  What i can do is manually download docker images(eg python) from docker hub and go thru security sheep dip process then burn them on to DVD. My private docker hub (Container 1) should have access this python image. So when user on Windows Server 2019 host, executes docker pull python, this comes from private hub. I am quite struggling how to execute this.

Comment: If you need this kind of security you should build your image yourself, then docker save: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

Comment: Or save registry container with your custom image inside, creating base for your private registry.